# In SuiteScript, what does 'nl' stand for such as nlapi...?

Tags: suitescript

This has been bothering me since I've been learning this API. I'm thinking it's probably related to "netsuite log" or "netsuite langauge" but there is no documentation of this anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a holdover from the original company name: [NetLedger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetSuite)

Answer (score 0):

This is Short form of Net Ledger, this was the original name of company, later was changed to NetSuite, but API was developed ay before so all functions were prefixed as nl (NetLedger).